# How to type multiple yield generator (redux-saga)

Tags: typescript, generator, redux-saga

our redux-saga generator contains multiple yield statements, that return different results.
I need help typing them properly.

Here's an example:

```js
const addBusiness = function* addBusiness(action: AddBusinessActionReturnType): Generator<
  Promise<Business> | SelectEffect | PutEffect<{ payload?: ActionPayload<Array<Business>>; type: string }>,
  void,
  Business | BusinessesContainer
> {
    const { url, showToast = true } = action.payload;

    const businessDetails: Business = yield Network.get<Business>( // ts error: Type 'Business | BusinessesContainer' is not assignable to type 'Business'.

      `businesses?url=${url}`,
    );

    if (showToast) {
      const getBusinessesFromState = (state: AppState) => ({
        ...state.business.businesses,
      });
      const businesses: BusinessesContainer = yield select(getBusinessesFromState); // ts error: Type 'Business | BusinessesContainer' is not assignable to type 'BusinessesContainer'
      onAddBusinessSuccessToast(businesses, businessDetails);
    }

    yield put({ // ts error: Type 'SimpleEffect<"PUT", PutEffectDescriptor<{ type: string; payload: Business[]; }>>' is not assignable to type 'SelectEffect'
      type: constants.SAVE_BUSINESS_REQUEST,
      payload: [businessDetails],
    });
```

In the comments above you see the ts errors that we get.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I know I've [done this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66895666/10431574) but your code doesn't look that different from the correct version.  I have to play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are definitely guilty of some over-typing here.  Certainly `yield Network.get<Business>()` returns a `Business`, right?  You shouldn't have to write `const businessDetails: Business` if the value that you are assigning to it is a `Business`.

These generator return types can be really hard to type properly, but Typescript is smart enough to figure out the proper type.  You could leave it off entirely and it would be fine.  If you've having a hard time figuring out the correct type you can delete the return type temporarily to see what the inferred type is.  That's how I resolved your first issue, which is that that the union `Business | BusinessesContainer` needs to be changed to an intersection `Business & BusinessesContainer`.

I don't know what the `ActionPayload` type is but it seems unnecessary.  You are typing the payload of your `put` action as `ActionPayload<Array<Business>>`, but `Array<Business>` is correct on its own.  There's no reason for the `payload` to be optional when you are always providing it.

Those two changes solve your typescript issues...for now.  I usually see API calls executed inside a [`call` effect](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args), which would make the types even more complex.  But I'm not sure if the `call` is actually required.

```
const addBusiness = function* addBusiness(action: AddBusinessActionReturnType): Generator<
  Promise<Business> | SelectEffect | PutEffect<{ payload: Array<Business>; type: string }>,
  void,
  Business & BusinessesContainer
> {
    const { url, showToast = true } = action.payload;

    const businessDetails: Business = yield Network.get<Business>( `businesses?url=${url}` );

    if (showToast) {
      const getBusinessesFromState = (state: AppState) => ({
        ...state.business.businesses,
      });
      const businesses: BusinessesContainer = yield select(getBusinessesFromState);
      onAddBusinessSuccessToast(businesses, businessDetails);
    }

    yield put({
      type: "SAVE_BUSINESS_REQUEST",
      payload: [businessDetails],
    });
  }

// dummy types that I filled in to check types

type Business = {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

type BusinessesContainer = {
  businesses: Business[];
}

const Network = {
  get: async <T>(url: string): Promise<T> => {
    return {} as unknown as T;
  }
}

type AddBusinessActionReturnType = {
  type: string;
  payload: {
    showToast?: boolean;
    url: string;
  }
}

type AppState = {
  business: {
    businesses: BusinessesContainer;
  }
}

const onAddBusinessSuccessToast = (businesses: BusinessesContainer, businessDetails: Business) => undefined;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.
That does resolve the issue for me indeed.
Question, doesn't `Business & BusinessesContainer` mean that the response is both a business AND a business container? Isn't that technically wrong since in reality it's EITHER one OR the other (and not both)?

Comment: It does seem counter-intuitive and to be honest I don’t understand the Generator types well enough to explain to you why it works.  I kind of hate generators and saga.

Comment: It works because you created a union of both types, so either Business and BusinessesContainer will fit into that union. Having said that I think it's not the right way to go, even though it doesn't complain. Imagine you have another yield that yields a string in there.

I'm also not a fan of generators, sagas and typing them :)