Define type of response after using call effect in redux-saga
I am using redux-saga to call API in nextjs ver.13 with typescript. This is my watcher
function* getNoteListWorker(): Generator<any, void, any> {
  try {
    const getNoteListApi = async () => await apiService.get("/note/list");
    const response = yield call(getNoteListApi);
    console.log(response)
    if (response.status === 200) {
      yield put(NoteAction.getNoteListSuccess(response.data));
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    yield put(NoteAction.getNoteListFail(error.response.data.message));
  }
}

This is my response when I console.log(response)

As you can see, the variable response has any type, so my editor shows warning at that. How can I define type for response in Generator<type_1 , type_2, type_3>? And the error in catch, if I do not give it an any type, it shows the warning in editor 'error' is of type 'unknown'.. How can I fix these problem? Thank for your help!

I'm not sure if using the Generator type there is correct. Is this Github comment helpful?

@sallf in your comment,i see that he defined for payload, not for generator function. If my worker have action, I will define the action like this function* createNoteWorker(action: Effect) with Effect type import from redux-saga/effects

This one is rough.  I can get call(getNoteListApi) to return a CallEffect with the correct response type in the generics, but yield call(getNoteListApi) just gives any.  You might need to put the type in manually const response: AxiosResponse<NoteList> = yield call(getNoteListApi); but I don't understand why it can't be inferred.

I've answered similar questions before.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66895666/10431574 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814984/10431574 Typing these sagas is a pain in the ass and honestly there's not much benefit.  You might want to ignore the IDE warnings.  For the best safety you should catch (error: unknown) and validate that the error has the shape you expect before using it.
